# Question About splitting a string with Regular Expression in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning some regular Expressions.

Now am I trying to get the street and the house number out of a string.

So this is my string "Driesstraat(Ide) 20".
Driesstraat is the street name.
(Ide) is an acronym for the municipality.
20 is the house number.

```
let re =   /^(\d*[\p{L} \d'\/\\\-\.]+)[,\s]+(\d+)\s*([\p{L} \d\-\/'"\(\)]*)$/iu
    
let match = adresInput.value.match(re)
if (match){
 match.shift();
    
 console.log(match.join('|'));
}
```

The above code works when their is no (Ide). I get this string out of a Belgian Eid reader.

thank you in advance

Comment: Your pattern seems overly complicated for simply finding a number in a string. What kind of street names requires all these rules?

Comment: If you do need all these conditions, simply add the brackets chars to the first group definition. Like this `(\d*[\p{L} \d'\/\\\-\.()]+)`

Comment: Is this the only string that you want to match for this exact format?

Comment: @Gil

Here is a list of some examples:
Driesstraat(Ide) 20,
Driesstraat 20,
Driesstraat 158 /A000,
Dorpstraat 2,
Dorpstr. 2,
Laan 1933 2,
18 Septemberplein 12,
Kerkstraat 42-f3,
Kerk straat 2b,
42nd street, 1337a,
1e Constantijn Huigensstraat 9b,
Maas-Waalweg 15,
De Dompelaar 1 B,
Kümmersbrucker Straße 2,
Friedrichstädter Straße 42-46,
Höhenstraße 5A,  
Saturnusstraat 60-75,
Saturnusstraat 60 - 75,
Plein \'40-\'45 10,
Plein 1945 1,
Steenkade t/o 56,
Steenkade a/b Twee Gezusters,
1, rue de l\'eglise

Comment: @Gil Thanks I just set de () like this `(\d*[\p{L} .() \d'\/\\\-\.]+)` so then I have the (Ide) after Driesstraat otherwise it just was deleted. I also understand it better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, `(...)` is not matched with your `(\d*[\p{L} \d'\/\\\-\.]+)` pattern, so you need to add `(?:\(\p{L}*\))?` or `(?:\([^()]*\))?` right after that pattern to optionally match a part of a string between parentheses. `(?:\(\p{L}*\))?` will match only letters between round brackets and `(?:\([^()]*\))?` will match any chars other than `(` and `)` between round brackets.

Besides, when using regular expressions with `/u` flag you must make sure you only escape what must be escaped inside character classes. It means, you overescaped several chars inside `[...]`. You need not escape `(`, `)`, `.` and you can even avoid escaping `-` when if it is put at the end of the character class. The chars that must be escaped inside character classes in ECMAScript regex flavor are `\`, `]`, and `^` must be escaped if it is at the start of the character class. Although the `-` can also be escaped it is best practice to put it at the end of the character class unescaped.

So, you can use

```js
/^(\d*[\p{L} \d'/\\.-]+)(?:\([^()]*\))?[,\s]+(\d+)\s*([\p{L} \d/'"()-]*)$/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/etsydk/2).

Note you do not even have to escape `/` inside character classes in ECMAScript regex flavor in JavaScript.

See a JavaScript test:

```js
let re = /^(\d*[\p{L} \d'/\\.\-]+)(?:\([^()]*\))?[,\s]+(\d+)\s*([\p{L} \d/'"()-]*)$/u;        
console.log(re.test("Driesstraat(Ide) 20"));
```